# How to rename file while replacing multiple characters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do a sweep of a folder every 15 minutes and send new files to an SFTP server. Sometimes the file would come in with with [ and ] in the file name and the SFTP command doesn't send it to the server, so I figured I could replace the '[' and ']' with '(' and ')' respectively. Below is my relevant code.

```
foreach($file in $files)
{
    if($file.PSIsContainer -eq $false)
    {
        #$file.FullName;
        #$file.Name; 
        if ($file.Name.Contains("[") -and $file.Name.Contains("]"))
        { 
            $file.FullName;
            $file.Name.Replace("[","(")
            $file.Name.Replace("]",")")
            #$Rename-Item $NewName {$file.Name -replace "[", "("}
        }
```

I have seen that the `Rename-Item $NewName {$file.Name -replace "[", "("}` works but that is only to change 1 character of the file. In my case I need to make 2 changes. I currently can't find online where someone is trying to replace 2 characters of a file and also rename it.

This is what I am trying to do.
`Text[1].txt -> Text(1).txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the `-replace` command. Use it as such:

```
$file.Name -replace "\[", "(" -replace "\]", ")"
```

Comment: I get the error `The regular expression pattern [ is not valid`

Comment: Updated to fix RegEx. Added `\\` escape character so that it takes the bracket as a literal character instead of the opening of a character series.